# Howto use Linux 64 Bit Machine to compile Qt Application for 32 bit armV7

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, armv7, odroid

I an developing for an Odroid XU4 which is ARM V7 32 Bit Ubuntu MATE. 
I know that I could develop on the embedded device directly, but this is not a suitable setup for my Team. Thus I would like to develop on my 64 Bit Linux maptop and cross compile for the 32 Bit armV7. 
I use QtCreator for development

What I did so far to make the cross compile work is

- compiled all libraries that I need (e.g. openCV) on my Odroid and
  copied them to my Linux 64Bit to use for cross compile
- downloaded the correct CrossCompiler (gcc-linaro-7.1.1-2017.08-x86_64_arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi-g++)
- compiled qt 5.9 on the odroid and copied to the linux machine to be used for cross compile

Now I setup a new Kit in qtCreator and define the correct qmake location. This is when I get the error, that the architecture is false (naturally since I compiled it on a 32 Bit)

So the question is, how do I have to build qt in order to us it for cross compiling an app for the target platform armV7 (32 bit) on a 64 bit linux laptop

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to say, your question is not understandable , especially the last statement. are you trying use the Qt libraries build for 32 bit ARM on your 64 bit x86-64 Linux machine? or do you want to cross-compile qt libraries for ARM using your x86-64 Linux machine?

Comment: Sorry about that, i will try to rephrase it